# J2ME PIM EVENTS

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui, jsr75, pim

I'm currently developing a J2ME application event manager. I'm using PIM but I don't have enough knowledge on this. Can someone help me or give me references on how to set in displaying, editing and deleting records?

Here's what I've done so far.

```
        import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
        import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
        import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
        import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
        import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
        import javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField;
        import javax.microedition.lcdui.DateField;
        import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
        import javax.microedition.lcdui.Alert;

        import javax.microedition.pim.PIM;
        import javax.microedition.pim.PIMItem;
        import javax.microedition.pim.EventList;
        import javax.microedition.pim.Event;
        import javax.microedition.pim.PIMException;

        import java.util.Date;


        public class AddCalendarEvent extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

            private Display display;
            private Form addEventForm;
            private Command cmdAddEvent;
            private Command cmdExit;
            private TextField summaryField;
            private DateField startDateField;
            private DateField endDateField;
            private TextField noteField;
            private TextField locationField;

            public AddCalendarEvent() {
                if(checkPIMSupport() == false) {
                    exitMIDlet();
                }

                initializeComponents();
            }

            public void initializeComponents() {
                display = Display.getDisplay(this);
                addEventForm = new Form("Add event");
                cmdAddEvent = new Command("Add event", Command.SCREEN, 0);
                addEventForm.addCommand(cmdAddEvent);

                cmdExit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
                addEventForm.addCommand(cmdExit);

                addEventForm.setCommandListener(this);        

                try {
                    EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(
                            PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);
                    if(eventList.isSupportedField(Event.SUMMARY) == true) {
                        summaryField = new TextField("Summary", null, 20, 
                                                    TextField.ANY);
                        addEventForm.append(summaryField);
                    } else {
                        eventList.close();
                        throw new Exception("Summary field is not supported");
                    }

                    if(eventList.isSupportedField(Event.START) == true) {
                        startDateField = new DateField("Start date", 
                                                    DateField.DATE_TIME);
                        startDateField.setDate(new Date());
                        addEventForm.append(startDateField);
                    }

                    if(eventList.isSupportedField(Event.END) == true) {
                        endDateField = new DateField("End date", DateField.DATE_TIME);
                        endDateField.setDate(new Date());
                        addEventForm.append(endDateField);
                    }

                    if(eventList.isSupportedField(Event.NOTE) == true) {
                        noteField = new TextField("Note", null, 20, TextField.ANY);
                        addEventForm.append(noteField);
                    }

                    if(eventList.isSupportedField(Event.LOCATION) == true) {
                        locationField = new TextField("Location", null, 20, 
                                                    TextField.ANY);
                        addEventForm.append(locationField);
                    }            

                    eventList.close();

                } catch(PIMException pimExc) {
                }
                catch(SecurityException secExc) {

                }
                catch(Exception exc) {

                    exitMIDlet();
                }
            }

            private boolean checkPIMSupport() {
                String propValue = System.getProperty("microedition.pim.version");
                if(propValue != null) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            private void addEvent() {
                try {
                    EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(
                            PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);            

                    Event event = eventList.createEvent();

                    if(eventList.isSupportedField(Event.SUMMARY) == true) {
                        String summary = summaryField.getString();
                        event.addString(Event.SUMMARY, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, summary);
                    } else {
                        eventList.close();
                        throw new Exception("Summary field for event is not supported");
                    }

                    if(eventList.isSupportedField(Event.START) == true) {
                        long startDate = startDateField.getDate().getTime();
                        event.addDate(Event.START, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, startDate);
                    }

                    if(eventList.isSupportedField(Event.END) == true) {
                        long endDate = endDateField.getDate().getTime();
                        event.addDate(Event.END, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, endDate);
                    }

                    if(eventList.isSupportedField(Event.NOTE) == true) {
                        String note = noteField.getString();
                        event.addString(Event.NOTE, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, note);
                    }

                    if(eventList.isSupportedField(Event.LOCATION) == true) {
                        String location = locationField.getString();
                        event.addString(Event.LOCATION, PIMItem.ATTR_NONE, location);
                    }      

                    event.commit();
                    eventList.close();

                    showAlert("Info", "Event was successfully added.");

                } catch(PIMException pimExc) {
                    showAlert("PIMException", pimExc.getMessage());
                }
                catch(SecurityException secExc) {
                    showAlert("SecurityException", secExc.getMessage());
                }
                catch(Exception exc) {
                    showAlert("Exception", exc.getMessage());
                }   
            }

            private void showAlert(String title, String message) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(title);
                alert.setString(message);
                alert.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
                display.setCurrent(alert);
            }

            public void startApp() {
                display.setCurrent(addEventForm);
            }

            public void pauseApp() {
            }
            public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
            }

            private void exitMIDlet() {
                notifyDestroyed();
            }

            public void commandAction(Command command, Displayable displayable) {
                if(command == cmdAddEvent) {
                    addEvent();
                }

                if(command == cmdExit) {
                    exitMIDlet();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what exactly are you having problem with?

Comment: I'm having problem displaying, editing and deleting data in pim. Don't have any references.

Comment: there are references to specification and tutorials provided in **[jsr75 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsr75/info "here")** - like "getting Started with PIM API". Did you check these?

Comment: I haven't check this out yet. Thanks alot sir @gnat.

Comment: -1 I'm afraid, this really is a lousy question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Study the specification and tutorials suggested in [jsr75 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsr75/info) .

This one looks like the best match to your issues: **[Getting Started With the PIM APIs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-139790.html)**

> ...This article provides a code-intensive introductory tutorial to the PIM APIs; it:
>
> - Introduces JSR 75
> - Describes the `javax.microedition.pim` optional package
> - Provides details about the PIM APIs
> - Offers a taste of the effort involved in using them
> - Provides code that you can adapt to the needs of your own wireless applications
>
> ...

Above tutorial also lists some resources recommended for further study in section **For more information**.